# Muxing h264 stream into mp4

Tags: libav

I've a H.264 stream (`.264`). How do I pack (mux) it into a `.mp4` file? I know I need to use `avconv`, but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
avconv -i input.264 -c:v copy output.mp4
```

Alternatively,

```
MP4Box -add input.264 output.mp4
```

You can install MP4Box with

```
sudo apt-get install gpac
```